# Tools for analyzing Perl 5 code?

Tags: tools, vulnerability-scanners, source-code, perl

I'm looking for good tools for analyzing and/or detecting security issues in a large software project written in Perl 5. It could be static or dynamic analysis. I know that Perl is [undecidable](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=663393), but I'm decided to try any tool that allow me to reduce the work need to review such a large amount of code.

I tested [RATS](http://www.darknet.org.uk/2009/11/rats-rough-auditing-tool-for-security/), but it only looks for a very small and limited number of vulnerabilities.

Answer (score 6):

CERT has create a [CERT Perl Secure Coding Standard](https://www.securecoding.cert.org/confluence/display/perl/CERT+Perl+Secure+Coding+Standard) and there's been discussion of having Perl::Critic have a set of policies that match their standard.  As far as I know, nothing's been done yet.  Here's the [start of the discussion](http://perlcritic.tigris.org/ds/viewMessage.do?dsForumId=4230&dsMessageId=2972097) on the Perl::Critic dev mailing list.

Answer (score 4):

Try "Perl::Critic". I haven't used it yet but i came across the answer of a similar question in the below link:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1149447/perl-code-security-scanner-other-than-rats-must-be-static

link to the Perl::Critic details:
http://search.cpan.org/~thaljef/Perl-Critic-1.118/lib/Perl/Critic.pm

Comment: A permanent link to Perl::Critic that isn't tied to a specific version is http://search.cpan.org/dist/Perl-Critic/

Comment: Perl::Critic mostly deals with the way you write your code. A huge legacy app would fail this miserably. There are IDEs like Komodo that have Critic support built-in, like syntax checking. it will squiggle things it deems wrong, depending on its configuration. But many of the default rules aren't very security-relevant. It's more a question of coding style really. A typical application would be to have a standard set of rules and let your git/svn check against these in a pre-commit hook.